# How to get a signal when layout has changed in Awesome Wm

Tags: awesome-wm

Is is possible to capture the layout change in Awesome 3.5 like this for the tags ( for example):

```
screen[s]:connect_signal("tag::history::update", function()                     
   --do some stuff when virtual desktop has changed
end
```

If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the `layout` of a tag is changed, `awful.layout.set` just calls `awful.tag.setproperty` to set the "layout" property of the tag. This will then emit the "property::layout" signal on the tag.

Here is how to connect to this signal for any tag (only works in awesome 3.5, not 3.4):

```
tag.connect_signal("property::layout", function(t)
    print("Layout of tag " .. t.name .. " is now function " .. awful.tag.getproperty(t, "layout"))
end)
```

For a specific tag object `t`, you can also use the following code. This will only run when the layout of just that tag changes.

```
t:connect_signal("property::layout", function() print("Layout changed") end)
```